# Drawing things on a Canvas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, canvas, drawing

How would I draw something on a Canvas in C# for Windows Phone?

Okay, let me be a little more clear.

Say the user taps his finger down at 386,43 on the canvas. (the canvas is 768 by 480)

I would like my application to be able to respond by placing a red dot at 386,43 on the canvas.

I have **no** prior experience with Canvas whatsoever.

**If** this is too complex to be answered in one question (which it probably is), *please* give me links to other websites with Canvas and Drawing articles.

Comment: I feel like starting to downvote every question that includes an explicit request for inclusion of code in answers. If I can help you without showing code, you don't want my help?

Comment: I agree, it's a bit rude. I'm willing to give the benefit of doubt here since it's a very simple piece of code.

Comment: If you don't know a thing about C#, you shouldn't be coding in it. Harsh but true. Go learn C# and then you don't need to ask for only answers with code.

Comment: @Martinho: Well, from experience with Java, just jumping in and writing code **does** help me learn. Also, I meant that I have no experience with C# Canvas. I do have **some** experience with C#.

Comment: Anyhow, sorry for my request of code - as you can see, I've edited it out. To be clear, I'd have been fine with pretty much any help. {I just noticed this question again, now that it just won me a Notable Question badge, and wanted to clean it up.}

Comment: Hi so did you end up using the Canvas? I want to draw a 1000 points where the user needs to be able to select some points and apply functions to them selected points. Would you recommend a better approach after your experience?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this. Depending on the nature of the red dot, you could make it a UserControl. For a basic circle, you can simply handle your canvas' `ManipulationStarted` event.

```
private void myCanvas_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{

            Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
            el.Width = 10;
            el.Height = 10;
            el.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            Canvas.SetLeft(el, e.ManipulationOrigin.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(el, e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);
            myCanvas.Children.Add(el);
}
```

Comment: Hi what if I want every dot to be clickable and a UserControl? And let's say I have a 1000 points where the user _clicks_ on some dots to apply some functionality to them

Comment: @FirstStep - Hi. Might be worth creating a new question (or seeing if it's been answered elsewhere) but you can attach the `MouseDown` event to the `el` object above. In the event handler, cast the `sender` to `Ellipse` and you'll have the instance that was clicked on. Hope that's what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to approach the problem differently.  (I'm not including code on purpose, because of that).

Forms and controls in an Windows applications (including Phone) can be refreshed for several reasons, at any time.  If you draw on a canvas in response to a touch action, you have an updated canvas until the next refresh.  If a refresh occurs the canvas repaints itself, you end up with a blank canvas.

I have no idea what your end goal is, but you likely want to either keep track of what the user has done and store that state somewhere and show it in a canvas on the repaint of the canvas.  This could be done with storing all the actions and "replaying" them on the canvas, or simply storing the view of the canvas as a bitmap and reload the canvas with that bitmap when refreshed.  But, in the later case I think using a canvas isn't the right solution.

Comment: It **may** be a solution if Windows Phone supports screenshots later in the future-but that capability will probably come after I release my app. Also, I agree with you, maybe using a canvas isn't the right solution.

Comment: Hi Peter do you mean like simply use an Image control on the gui and on every user click evet draw a new bitmap image with the new changes? Where the bmp image is bound to the Image Control?