# how to draw a line on tapped point inside canvas

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am using a canvas control in my windows phone 8 application, and I want a line to be drawn on the point where user taps the canvas. I want to take the co ordinates of the tapped point and then draw a line with x1 being tappedpoint.X-50 and x2 being tappedpoint.X+50,please give any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of resources out there for this...

- [Drawing things on a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008895/drawing-things-on-a-canvas)
- http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7MultiTouchDrawing-4513213a

etc. etc.